# How to change RabbitMQ default password

Tags: rabbitmq

How to change the rabbitMQ default guest user/password

docker-compose.yaml

version: "3.8"

services:

rabbitmq3:

```
    container_name: "rabbitmq"

    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine

    environment:

        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=myuser

        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypassword

    ports:

        # AMQP protocol port

        - '5672:5672'

        # HTTP management UI

        - '15672:15672'
```

rabbitMQ container getting restarted after updating username and password in a docker-compose file and I have changed the default user name and password in rabitmq.conf but the issue remains the same.

I mentioned below one in setting.py
amqp://password:user@localhost:5672/

Comment: The default management credentials for the docker image are: `guest`/`guest` in case someone is wondering. See [docker image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq)